# Can Efficiency of a normal engine in other dimensions be 100%?

Tags: thermodynamics

While I was imagining about carnot engine I got this question whether we can achieve a 100% efficient engine in other dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The efficiency of the most efficient engine or Carnot engine is given by $n=1-{Q_2\over Q_1}$

For $100$% efficiency, $Q_2$ must be zero which would mean that all heat from the source is converted into heat. This violates the second law of thermodynamics as absolute temperature cannot be negative. This remains unchanged by the number of dimensions in space. Hence the efficiency would be the same.

Comment: Thank you Sam .

Answer (score 1):

Carnote's theorem basically follows from the definition of temperature, the conservation of energy and the second law. Non-of these notions depend on notions like dimension. It does not really matter how you make your heat engine, all that matters in the flow of energy through it. So the limits on the efficency of a heat engine are not changed in higher (or lower) dimensions.

Comment: Thank you symmetry.